# SQL Server dynamic parameters join stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

This my stored procedure and parameters but I need to do dynamic search

```
SELECT
  dbo.Invoices.*, 
  dbo.Vessels.Name AS VesselName, 
  dbo.Companies.Name AS CompanyName,
  dbo.InvoiceTypes.Name AS InvoiceTypeName, 
  dbo.InvoiceItems.Name AS InvoiceItemName, 
  dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID
FROM            
  dbo.Invoices 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Vessels ON 
    dbo.Invoices.VesselID = dbo.Vessels.VesselID 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Companies ON 
    dbo.Invoices.CompanyID = dbo.Companies.CompanyID 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.InvoiceTypes ON 
    dbo.Invoices.InvoiceTypeID = dbo.InvoiceTypes.InvoiceTypeID 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems ON 
    dbo.Invoices.InvoiceID = dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceID 
  LEFT JOIN dbo.InvoiceItems ON 
    dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID = dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID
```

PARAMETERS

```
@InvoiceItemID int,
@InvoiceTypeID int,
@VesselID int,
@PaidByID int,
@InvoiceNo NVarchar(50),
@CompanyID int,
@chkSearchInvoiceDate bit,
@chkSearchIsDueDate bit,
@chkSearchIsPaid bit,
@chkSearchReceived bit,
@chkSearchAmount bit,
@chkSearchInvoiceType bit,
@InvoiceFromDate    DateTime,
@InvoiceToDate    DateTime,
@FromDueDate    DateTime,
@ToDueDate     DateTime, 
@FromAmount decimal(18,4),
@ToAmount decimal(18,4)
```

But I tried it what do I do when there are multiple where? I could not :(

Thank you

```
Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000)    
Set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT dbo.Invoices.*, dbo.Vessels.Name AS VesselName, dbo.Companies.Name AS CompanyName, dbo.InvoiceTypes.Name AS InvoiceTypeName, 
                 dbo.InvoiceItems.Name AS InvoiceItemName, dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID' 

If @InvoiceItemID Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'FROM dbo.Invoices LEFT JOIN  dbo.InvoiceItems ON dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID = dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID WHERE dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID = @InvoiceItemID'

If @VesselID Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'LEFT JOIN  dbo.Vessels ON dbo.Vessels.VesselID = dbo.Invoices.VesselID WHERE dbo.Invoices.VesselID = @VesselID'

If @InvoiceNo Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo'

If @CompanyID Is Not Null
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE dbo.Invoices.CompanyID = @CompanyID'

If @chkSearchInvoiceDate >  0
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE Between @InvoiceFromDate and @InvoiceToDate'

If @chkSearchIsDueDate >  0
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE Between @FromDueDate and @ToDueDate'

If @chkSearchIsPaid >  0
     Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE dbo.Invoices.PaidBy = @PaidBy'

If @chkSearchReceived >  0
      Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + 'WHERE dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to use multiple parameters in the `where` clause at the same time you can add them like this:

```
Declare @SQLQuery AS NVarchar(4000)
Declare @ParamDefinition AS NVarchar(2000)    
Set @SQLQuery = '
SELECT 
    dbo.Invoices.*, 
    dbo.Vessels.Name AS VesselName, 
    dbo.Companies.Name AS CompanyName, 
    dbo.InvoiceTypes.Name AS InvoiceTypeName, 
    dbo.InvoiceItems.Name AS InvoiceItemName, 
    dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID
FROM dbo.Invoices 
LEFT JOIN dbo.InvoiceItems ON dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID = dbo.InvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Vessels ON dbo.Vessels.VesselID = dbo.Invoices.VesselID 
WHERE 1=1 ' 

If @InvoiceItemID Is Not Null
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.InvoiceVsInvoiceItems.InvoiceItemID = @InvoiceItemID'

If @VesselID Is Not Null
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.VesselID = @VesselID'

If @InvoiceNo Is Not Null
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo'

If @CompanyID Is Not Null
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.CompanyID = @CompanyID'

If @chkSearchInvoiceDate >  0
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND InvoiceDate Between @InvoiceFromDate and @InvoiceTODate'

If @chkSearchIsDueDate >  0
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND IsDueDate Between @FromDueDate and @ToDueDate'

If @chkSearchIsPaid >  0
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.PaidBy = @PaidByID'

If @chkSearchReceived >  0
    Set @SQLQuery = @SQLQuery + ' AND dbo.Invoices.InvoiceNo = @InvoiceNo'
```

Comment: Is cast for @VesselID really needed?

Comment: @JamesZ I think it is needed to be able to concat string and integer. The same goes for all other parameters that are injected.

Comment: Did I misread or did you edit this... I think the variables are supposed to be in the SQL text instead of the values and values given separately to  sp_execute_sql?

Comment: I would recommend using sp_execute_sql with the variables, otherwise there's a chance for SQL injection and cache bloating

Comment: @JamesZ Oh right, I did misread it. Edited. Misunderstood that it was supposed to be params to executesql